# Dynamically create a 3 different tables in one page layout

Tags: c#, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have to show 3 different tables in one page layout. User can edit the table and some business functionalities involved. I can develop one table in jquery and bind it in front end its working.

Question[edited] I have a got an idea to create object in Typescript and maintain different instances for each table data. Hope it should work. Let me implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: Hi JohnB, as you suggested I have edited my question.